# What if the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function doesn't fire when using rx.items?

Tags: swift, delegates, datasource

No matter how much I searched, I couldn't solve the problem, so I'm asking a question.
I am trying to bind data received using rxswift to collectionView using rx.items.
For each cell, bind is normally performed, but a problem occurs in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout function.
As a result of checking, the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function that sets the header is not called,
In the case of the referenceSizeForHeaderInSection function, it is called multiple times, more than once.
And if you use CollectionViewDataSource instead of rx.items, Header is normally displayed in CollectionView. Is there any workaround for this?

```swift
//
//  ProfileViewController.swift
//  TwitterProject(Rx+MVVM)
//
//  Created by 강창혁 on 2023/01/05.
//

import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import SnapKit
import RxViewController


class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelBindable {
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var viewModel: ProfileViewModel!
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return collectionView
    }()
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureUI()
    }
    // MARK: - Methods
    
    func configureUI() {
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        collectionView.register(TweetCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(ProfileHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    func bindViewModel() {
        // - input
        collectionView.rx.setDelegate(self)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        let viewWillAppear = self.rx.viewWillAppear
        
        viewWillAppear.asDriver()
            .drive(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        viewWillAppear
            .bind(to: viewModel.input.viewWillAppear)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        viewModel.output.userTweets
            .bind(to: self.collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, cellType: TweetCell.self)) { index, tweet, cell in
                let tweetCellModel = TweetCellModel(tweet: tweet)
                cell.bind(cellModel: tweetCellModel)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
extension ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        print(#function)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 350)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 120)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileHeaderView
        header.viewModel = self.viewModel
        header.bindViewModel()
        return header
    }
}
```

Drawing the Header is in charge of the delegate, not the dataSource. I wonder if this problem occurs when the datasource is not used.